# Concourse tasks fail with 'failed to stream out from volume' error

Tags: docker, google-cloud-platform, centos7, concourse

I have Concourse/Fly version 4.2.2 installed on a google cloud VM, running CentOS 7. Everything is up and running, including concourse-web and concourse-fly services. When I try to execute a simple task, it fails with 'Failed to stream out from volume' error.

I see the same error when I attempt to run any of the tutorials as well. I have docker and docker-compose installed on the VM.

```
[prashanth@concourse-ci ~]$ uname -r
4.20.2-1.el7.elrepo.x86_64

[prashanth@concourse-ci ~]$ cat test.yml
---
platform: linux

image_resource:
  type: docker-image
  source:
     repository: busybox


run:
  path: uname
  args: [-a]

[prashanth@concourse-ci ~]$ sudo systemctl status concourse-web
● concourse-web.service - Concourse CI web server
    Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/concourse-web.service; 
enabled; vendor preset: disabled)
  Active: active (running) since Wed 2019-01-16 14:50:50 UTC; 56min ago
 Main PID: 26406 (concourse)
 Tasks: 13

[prashanth@concourse-ci ~]$ sudo systemctl status concourse-worker
● concourse-worker.service - Concourse CI worker process
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/concourse-worker.service; 
enabled; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: active (running) since Wed 2019-01-16 14:32:38 UTC; 1h 
14min ago
 Main PID: 25127 (concourse)
 Tasks: 18
 Memory: 228.6M

[prashanth@concourse-ci ~]$ fly -t test status
logged in successfully
[prashanth@concourse-ci ~]$ fly -t test e -c test.yml
executing build 6 at http://35.192.60.127:8080/builds/6
initializing
failed to stream out from volume
errored
```

Am I running into some unknown permissions issues? I don't see any docker containers created after the command is run. Any pointers would be great